# How to run meteor server on a different ip address?

Tags: meteor

How can i start meteor server on a different IP address? Currently in the examples am only able to run on a localhost:3000 address.

Comment: Have you considered marking the `BIND_IP` answer as correct?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

According to `netstat -tapn` Meteor/Node.js listens on all available IP addresses on the machine:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9098/node
```

Do you have something like iptables running?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is checked as the correct answer. It doesn't answer the question. The `BIND_IP` answer works for me.

Comment: It does not really do that.

Answer (score 23):

export BIND_IP no longer works, bind IP is defined with --port (or -p or --app-port) option(s):

```
$ meteor run --port 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/9b8bd31a7b6c857e5d8fc0393982e6e6b2973eb0

Comment: With meteor's auto-updating "feature" some answers are correct at the time and then not correct later on.

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking to run something on another IP address (but still have the files local) you need to look into editing your vhosts file. If you are on a mac, look into [Virtual Host X](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/)

The proper way to change ports with meteor is this:

```
meteorapp : meteor --port 5000
```

Answer (score 12):

According to [this change](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/ae965f1aa15cc6befb2ba07c116f9844d679d0ce), you should be able to configure your app to bind to a specific IP address by configuring a `BIND_IP` environment variable.

```
export BIND_IP=127.0.0.1
```

You may need to update your app to a newer version of Meteor for this to work correctly.

Comment: This answer is no longer an option with new releases of Meteor

Answer (score 3):

Using Meteor 1.3.2.4, If your IP is 192.168.0.13 as in my case, on the terminal, type:

```
meteor --mobile-server 192.168.0.13
```

or

```
meteor --port 192.168.0.13:3000
```

And you will see the Meteor welcome page by typing

```
http://192.168.0.13:3000
```

on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you can't - meteor binds to all IP addresses, but there's an [issue open](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/159#issuecomment-5937698) to add support for binding to a specific IP.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy it on another server and connect to the internet-ip of the server from outside of the internal net, or connect to the local-ip of the server from the lan.

How to deploy on another server?

'meteor bundle'

and read the README

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible yet, but there is an open pull request for it.  They are waiting for the author to sign the meteor contributor agreement before it can be accepted.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/469/

If you need it before it's official you can apply the patch yourself (or potentially just replace 127.0.0.1 with the IP address you want to bind to in the same files references by the patch (app/lib/mongo_runner.js and app/meteor/run.js).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Meteor behaves differently in production and development environments.

### Production

Use environment variable `BIND_IP`

### Development

Use `--port` argument like `meteor run --port 192.168.1.1:port`

Docs [here](https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#BIND-IP)