# Meteor Deployment Strategies

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor deployment that I wish to run on port 80 of a server already running apache. I need a subdomain to point to the meteor deployment. I have already tried to use the apache's mod_proxy to create a proxy to the subdomain with meteor deployed on port 8080. However, mod_proxy doesn't work with web sockets. I have also tried to use the mod_proxy_wstunnel module but that doesn't seem to work either. The server has 5 IPs. So, I have also thought of deploying meteor on a separate IP from the one on which apache is deployed. However, meteor seems to bind to all 5 IPs. I couldn't find a way to separate meteor to unbind from the other Ips and bind to just one. Is there any way of solving this problem ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123633/how-to-run-meteor-server-on-a-different-ip-address

See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168921/1839099

Comment: Thanks for that. For now, we have meteor deployed on a separate server on port 80 and everything works fine. Not the most elegant solution but it works.

Comment: What about putting nginx in front of both servers and routing by http hostname?  That's a lot less resource intensive that proxying through Apache (and will cover any SSL requirements, and allow for load balancing if you ever need it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the nginx suggestion in comments, I have done this with [haproxy](http://blog.silverbucket.net/post/31927044856/3-ways-to-configure-haproxy-for-websockets).

Haproxy listens on port 80, passes requests to meteor's subdomain to port 3000, and leaves everything else to apache which I moved to port 8000.  Took minutes to setup, supports websockets, and I don't really notice haproxy running.

My haproxy config is based on link above and looks like this:

```
# this config needs haproxy-1.1.28 or haproxy-1.2.1
global
  daemon
  log /dev/log local0 info
  log /dev/log local0 notice

defaults
  log global
  maxconn 4096
  mode http
  option http-server-close
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s

frontend public
  # HTTP
  bind :80
  use_backend meteor if { hdr_end(Host) meteorSubdomain.yourDomain.com }

  default_backend apache

backend meteor
  server meteor1 127.0.0.1:3000

backend apache
  server apache1 127.0.0.1:8000
```