# Meteor JS, deploy app on 192.168.1.X?

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

How can I deploy my Meteor app on the address 192.168.1.21:25565?  I've started an HTTP server on that address with pure Node.js, but I can't seem to get it to work the same with Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if 192.168.1.21 is the address of the machine hosting your code, then just start it up with

```
meteor --port 25565
```

if that's not your problem, check out this post,
[How to run meteor server on a different ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123633/how-to-run-meteor-server-on-a-different-ip-address)