# Checking clients certificate in Meteor

Tags: javascript, ssl, meteor

Is there a way in Meteor to check a clients certificate, so that only a client who owns a specific certificate can connect to the server?

Basically I want a SSL connection, but with bidirectional authentification, so the client also has to proof his identity, not just the server.
The certificates can be self-signed, so not certificate authority is needed.

To make my question clearer: How can I access the clients certificate, when a connection is established?

Comment: I figured out, that the easiest way to accomplish this, would be to use something like nginx.<br/> 
Now I wonder if there is a way to force meteor to listen only to localhost. Does anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19254806/220060

Comment: @Tobson Would you be willing to answer your own question with how you accomplished that with nginx?