# Listen on 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 in bundled meteor app

Tags: meteor

I've bundled my meteor app and running it via "node main.js", how can I tell Node to listen on 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of 0.0.0.0:3000?

When I was using "Meteor run", I could use "Meteor run --port host:port" to specify the interface.

Here you can see the difference:

```
$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 PORT=3000 ROOT_URL=http://localhost/ node main.js

$ sudo netstat -anp                     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3126/node
```

vs.

```
$ meteor run --port 127.0.0.1:3000
$ sudo netstat -anp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3342/node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set BIND_IP using environmental variables:

```
export BIND_IP=127.0.0.1
export PORT=80
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost
node ./app/main.js
```

Based on :

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/ae965f1aa15cc6befb2ba07c116f9844d679d0ce

[How to run meteor server on a different ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123633/how-to-run-meteor-server-on-a-different-ip-address)